# Firebase Query returning wrong Values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPoy.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPe2x.jpg)I am trying to retrieve the number of messages not read by the user in my chat application. For this purpose, I am storing values in two different tables. First being "Chat" and another "messages". I am storing two values in my "Chat" Table in Firebase with values seen & timestamp, whenever a User sends a message to another user it stores the values in both "Chat" & "messages" tables. Message table stores values -From, Message, seen, time(this is a timestamp) & type. Problem is when I am running below query on firebase I expect it to return all the messages whose timestamp is after/greater than the timestamp value stored in "Chat" table.

```
 DatabaseReference chatdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()  
   .getReference().child("Chat").child(mCurrent_user_id).child(list_user_id);
 chatdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          timelast = ((long) dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue());
          //timestamp is the value in chat table which i use to compare 
          DatabaseReference mMsgDatabase =                      
           FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages")
                             .child(mCurrent_user_id).child(list_user_id);
         Query querymsg =mMsgDatabase.orderByChild("time").startAt(timelast);
         //  here i am retrieving a datasnapshot from Message table 
         querymsg.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
              {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
                   {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                     for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                           {
                           long i = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                           -- dislay number --
                           }
                       }
                   }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
         });
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
 });
```

I am expecting the query to return me messages after comparing the timestamps.I am confused as to why is my query returning a number even when i send a message it should return 1 when one message is sent. I have a question here that is it possible that for the query to return me values the values in the startat(timestamp) should exist in another table. Or if something is wrong with my code.

data structure

```
## Heading ##"Chat" : {
"7LVfrVRwZGb7HUcMNKkFxEJrAW52" : {
  "CNFnKyQdNbbwZd8FgFw6tp7WWXR2" : {
    "seen" : false,
    "timestamp" : 1548689212846
  }
},
"CNFnKyQdNbbwZd8FgFw6tp7WWXR2" : {
  "7LVfrVRwZGb7HUcMNKkFxEJrAW52" : {
    "seen" : true,
    "timestamp" : 1548689212844
  }
}


 "messages" : {
"7LVfrVRwZGb7HUcMNKkFxEJrAW52" : {
  "CNFnKyQdNbbwZd8FgFw6tp7WWXR2" : {
    "-LXJNEV30kuj8CazMSt3" : {
      "from" : "CNFnKyQdNbbwZd8FgFw6tp7WWXR2",
      "message" : "hi there",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1548677610585,
      "type" : "text"
    },
```

Comment: Can you please add your data structure to the question?

Comment: Also: please indent your code blocks properly, as right now it's quite hard to parse.

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also reponde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added two images of data structure.i hope it help

Comment: @Mocas i have added two images of data structure. please have a look

Comment: @HemuSharma So what is actually displaying?

Comment: it returns a number to me 5 everytime and i want it to give me a number of message whose creation time is greater tham the timestamp in Chat

Comment: i have a question here is it necessary for the timestamps to be exact to run the query . i mean when i say startat(timestamp) does it mean  there has to be some number which is equal to timestamp to run startat(timestamp)

Comment: @AlexMamo i am updating the timestamp in Chat table every time user send a message so that when the query runs it returns the values on the basis of that given timestamp in Chat

Comment: is it possible that i am passing long in startAt() is the reason why i am getting wrong values because startAt() requires a double.

Comment: i am getting number 5 even when i use startat() or endat() , i think probably the query is returning the right value

Comment: @HemuSharma What are the expected values?

Comment: @AlexMamo expected values are 2 because i have sent two messages after closing my messageActivity. They have the timestamp after the timestamp in "Chat" table

Comment: Have you tried to add also a endAt call?

Comment: I found the answer it was a silly mistake i was calling getchildrencount on wrong datasnapshot.